# Yii2 console app - cookieValidationKey config errors

Tags: php, wampserver, yii2-advanced-app

I have configured the `cookieValidationKey` inside my `backend\config\main.php` and `frontend\config\main.php` and removed it from `common\config\main.php`. But when I run `php yii` inside command line. I get this error.
Even before I set it inside to my backend config the error showed up when I used the command line.

```
$ php yii
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\console\Request:
:cookieValidationKey'

in D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:201

Stack trace:
#0 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(525): yii\base\Component->__set('cook
ieValidatio...', '9H2hvsco52yQ0N2...')
#1 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Obje
ct(yii\console\Request), Array)
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(381): ReflectionClass->newInstan
ceArgs(Array)
#4 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('y
ii\\console\\Req...', Array, Array)
#5 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\con
sole\\Req...', Array, Array)
#6 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(135): yii\BaseYii::createOb
ject(Array)
#7 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(219): yii\di\ServiceLocat
or->get('request')
#8 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\console\Applicatio
n->getRequest()
#9 D:\web\wamp64\www\html\royall.dev\yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

Why is this happening? I did not have `cookieValidationKey` inside my `console\config\main.php` so it should not Popup this error.

I use windows and wamp-server but I tested it on an Ubuntu server and it's returning the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your console command combined all configs before executing the actual action. There are some config params which are invalid to console actions but useful to web requests. The solution is to remove these params before executing console actions.
Add the following line

```
unset($config['components']['request']);
```

before

```
$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
```

in file `yii`.

Because I run web server via vagrant, I didn't test if there's side effect to web app run via yii command.

Comment: thanks, man! I removed the configs in common section and separated them into backend and frontend sections. it's working now.